# python regex expresesion for number with optional * at the end

Tags: python, regex

I'm struggling to find the regex pattern for following examples (in python)

> string should start with a number between 1 and 99 and can have 0, 1,
>   2 or 3 `*` markers at the end.  anything else is invalid

- `""` -> NOK (must at least contain a number)
- `"1"` -> ok
- `"99"` -> ok
- `"100"` -> NOK (max number is 99)
- `"1*"` -> ok
- `"1**"` -> ok
- `"1***"` -> ok
- `"1****"` -> NOK (max 3 *'s)
- `"99***"` -> ok
- `"*1"` -> NOK (* only at back)
- `"1*1"` -> NOK (* only at back)
- `"1 *"` -> NOK (contains a space : not digit or *)

I got this far : `"^[0-9]{1,2}|^([0-9]{1,2})(\Z\*)"`
but it doesn't catch the `"1*1"` or `"1 *"` cases :(

these are the python code and tests:

---

```
import re

class ControlePunt:
    @staticmethod
    def create(punt):
        should_start_with_number_and_may_end_with_marker = "^[0-9]{1,2}|^([0-9]{1,2})(\Z\*)"
        if re.match(should_start_with_number_and_may_end_with_marker, punt):
            return ControlePunt(punt)
        else:
            return NoControlePunt()

    def __init__(self, punt):
        self.punt = punt


class NoControlePunt(ControlePunt):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("")
```

---

```
import unittest

from ControlePunt import ControlePunt, NoControlePunt


class ValidControlePuntTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_valid_numeric(self):
        self.assertEqual(ControlePunt.__name__, type(ControlePunt.create("21")).__name__)

    def test_valid_numeric_with_1_marker(self):
        self.assertEqual(ControlePunt.__name__, type(ControlePunt.create("21*")).__name__)

    def test_valid_numeric_with_2_markers(self):
        self.assertEqual(ControlePunt.__name__, type(ControlePunt.create("21**")).__name__)

    def test_valid_numeric_with_3_markers(self):
        self.assertEqual(ControlePunt.__name__, type(ControlePunt.create("21***")).__name__)


class InvalidControlePuntTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_empty(self):
        self.assertEqual(NoControlePunt.__name__, type(ControlePunt.create("")).__name__)

    def test_only_marker(self):
        self.assertEqual(NoControlePunt.__name__, type(ControlePunt.create("*")).__name__)

    def test_non_numeric(self):
        self.assertEqual(NoControlePunt.__name__, type(ControlePunt.create("a1")).__name__)

    def test_marker_before_numbers(self):
        self.assertEqual(NoControlePunt.__name__, type(ControlePunt.create("*1")).__name__)

    def test_marker_surrounded_by_numbers(self):
        self.assertEqual(NoControlePunt.__name__, type(ControlePunt.create("1*1")).__name__)

    def test_containing_illegal_characters(self):
        self.assertEqual(NoControlePunt.__name__, type(ControlePunt.create("1 *")).__name__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: You just need an end marker, `$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this regex may helps?

```
should_start_with_number_and_may_end_with_marker = "^[1-9][0-9][\*]{0,3}"
```

Comment: gr8 that indeed work - thx !!   - sorry for late reply - I got distracted with other challenges :)

Answer (score 0):

Regex: `r'^[1-9][0-9]?[\*]{0,3}$'`

Matches test cases.

**Explanation**

- `^[1-9]` - 1 thru 9 is first character
- `[0-9]?` - optional second character 0 to 9
- `[\\*]{0,3}$` - 0 to 3 * at end of string